# How to save a Line Array as figure in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, save, figure

I have the following arrays:

```
x = [1,2,3;,4,5,6];
y = [0,1,2];
```

I want to plot each row X vs Y.  Usually, I did a for loop through X and plot individually.  I realized that we can write

`plot(x,y)`

and it automatically does the same.  One issue is that Matlab says this is a Line Array.  How do I apply the saveas command? I tried and I got the following error:

```
Conversion to matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line from cell is not possible.

Error in saveas (line 75)
                h(n) = hP;
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to plot function like "f(x)=y", It is impossible bucause there are two x values for each y. But you can try "f(x)=y" that is "plot(y,x)".

Comment: @nassertahani : you can do both. @mle0312 : Can you show us the way you used `saveas` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can repmat y for your purpose and avoid for loop ... like below code

```
x = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6];           %XData (2-by-3)

y = [ 0 , 1 , 2];              %Ydata (1-by-3)

nrx = size(x , 2);             % number of x rows

y_new = repmat(y, nrx , 1 );   % repeat y along row direction
```

so output will be like below

```
y_new = repmat(y, nrx , 1 )

y_new =

 0     1     2
 0     1     2
```

and finally plot your data (just keep in mind that you must transpose data because MATLAB plot every column)

```
 plot(x.',y_new.')     % plot(transpose(x),transpose(y))
```

output will be like this picture
[image: click here for picture]

I hope this will help you and sorry for my english